# Circle Mask on Non-Square Image while Maintaining Aspect Ratio using CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, css

How can we apply a circle mask to a non-square image and still maintain the original image's aspect ratio, ie. prevent the image from being squashed? The image should still fill the entire circle.

A CSS-only solution is preferred, otherwise jQuery/Javascript can be used.

**JSFiddle Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/vxLmrm0o/

[image]

```
.photo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 80px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 80px;
    -moz-border-radius: 80px;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
}

.photo-bg {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Use [`object-fit: cover`](https://medium.com/@chrisnager/center-and-crop-images-with-a-single-line-of-css-ad140d5b4a87) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a wrapper, and then set `overflow:hidden`? With the wrapper object being set relatively, and img absolutely, you could come up with something like:

```css
.wrapper{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}

img {
  position:absolute;
  width: 400px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://media.bestofmicro.com/R/O/464964/original/Facebook-logo-PSD.jpg" class="photo" />
</div>
```

If that's the overall outcome you're looking for.

---

I've noticed in your example you've set:

```
width: 160px;
height: 160px;
```

Which is *going* to bring a change to your aspect ratio.

By setting **only one** of these values, the other will be set to 'auto', meaning it will scale to your correct aspect ratio.

[example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/vxLmrm0o/1/)

but alas! This isn't right!

---

I see you've prefixed the `border-radius` property, and set it to `80px;`

I would see this as a bit of overkill, since vendor prefixes for this aren't really necessary. [see here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius)

Instead, you could set it to 50%, and use the non-prefixed version:

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

---

But you've still got this 'rectangle' issue. So instead, you could use a wrapper to solve this:

[example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/vxLmrm0o/3/)

---

This still has a few issues, the likes of `top:0;` is actually pointless since it was set on a position:relative and so bears no importance/use for this (it can only be used on other position types, for example `absolute;`)

---

finishing this off and tiding it up, you could be left with this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/vxLmrm0o/4/)

Or as my snippet shows above, you could 're write' it to this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/vxLmrm0o/5/)